# create hierarchy using two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchy

Data I am working with is below:

```
Name RefSecondary     RefMain
test  2               3   
bet   3               4   
get   1               2   
set   null            1   
net   3               5
```

I have done a very simple query which looks up the presence of values in dataframe and build hierarchy

```
sys_role = 'sample.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(sys_role,na_filter = False).apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.strip())
for i in range(count):
    for j in range(count):
        if df.iloc[i]['RefMain'] == df.iloc[j]['RefSecondary']:
            df.iloc[j, df.columns.get_loc('Name')] = "/".join([df.iloc[i]['Name'],df.iloc[j]['Name']])
    j = j+1
i = i+1
```

The results I am getting is below:

```
   Result          RefMain
0  get/test           3
1  test/bet           4
2  set/get            2
3  set                1
4  test/net           5
```

This is really slow and the logic doesn't work perfectly as well.  Is there a way I can get this done faster?

Logic needs to be as below:

> ```
>  1)Take a value from column RefMain,and find its correspoding RefSecondary value.  
>  2)Look up the RefSecondary value  in RefMain, 
>  3)If found Back to Step 1 and repeat.
>  4)This continues recursively till no value/null is found in RefSecondary column.
> ```

Resultant dataframe should look like below:

```
   Result            RefMain
0  set/get/test          3
1  set/get/test/bet      4
2  set/get               2
3  set                   1
4  set/get/test/net      5
```

Comment: The question is missing?

Comment: Updated to clarify

Comment: your logic is still not clear, can you try to explain how you got second row for RefMain=4

Comment: RefMain 4, has corresponding RefSecondary    value of 3. Now 3 Can be found in RefMain Column, and its corresponding  RefSecondary    is 2. Now 2 can be found in RefMain Column and its RefSecondary    is 1. Now 1 can be found in RefMain Column and its RefSecondary    is null or no match. SInce no match, hence the flow stops and all values are added up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a graph problem. You can try `networkx` as follows:

```
df = df.fillna(-1)

# create a graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# add reference as edges
G.add_edges_from(zip(df['RefMain'],df['RefSecondary'] ))

# rename the nodes accordingly
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=df.set_index('RefMain')['Name'].to_dict())


# merge the path list to the dataframe
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(nx.shortest_path(G)).T['null'], 
              left_on='Name', 
              right_index=True)

# new column:
df['Path'] = df['null'].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x[-2::-1]) )
```

Output:

```
   Name RefSecondary RefMain                         null              Path
0  test            2       3       [test, get, set, null]      set/get/test
1   bet            3       4  [bet, test, get, set, null]  set/get/test/bet
2   get            1       2             [get, set, null]           set/get
3   set         null       1                  [set, null]               set
4   net            3       5  [net, test, get, set, null]  set/get/test/net
```

Comment: `df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(nx.shortest_path(G)).T[-1]` this lie shows `KeyError: -1`

Comment: I did. For clarity I have written the code around how I load the Dataframe as well, just in case that be of some relevance.

Comment: Your original data was `nan` instead of `null` at row 4. is `null` the string `'null'`? Also, are the numbers `string` or `int`?

Comment: numbers are `int` , yes null is string `null`

Comment: In that case, replace the `[-1]` by `['null']`. See edit.

Comment: `df = df.fillna('-1')` does this line do anything? Removing the same still gives me the exact same result. Also `df['null']` comes up with column named null. When I try to change it different name. It errors out. Just for my understanding, what are we transposing `(nx.shortest_path(G)).T['NULL']`

Comment: no, it doesn't. You can remove it. If you want to see what you are transposing, you can print `nx.shortest_path(G)` and `pd.DataFrame(nx.shortest_path(G))` to see (I did that too)

Comment: relabel_nodes seems to be removing duplicate names. Any chance that can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

following code lookup for a ref (1 in this case ) until no row is found. It outputs

```py
def lookup(df, ref):
    arr_result=[]
    result = []
    row = df[df.RefMain==ref]
    while len(row)>0:
        arr_result.append(row.Name.iloc[0])
        result.append(("/".join(arr_result), row.RefMain.iloc[0]))
        row = df[df.RefSecondary == row.RefMain.iloc[0] ]

    return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=["Result", "RefMain"])

lookup(df,1)
```

**Output**

```
Result  RefMain
0   set 1
1   set/get 2
2   set/get/test    3
3   set/get/test/bet    4
```

in the question above how do you get row "set/get/test/net      5", did I miss something or it is a mistake?

Comment: I have updated the question with what I have done till now.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the column `RefMain` as index and access strings using the method `reindex()`:

```
# Convert 'RefSecondary' to numeric and set 'RefMain' as index
df['RefSecondary'] = pd.to_numeric(df.RefSecondary, errors='coerce')
df.set_index('RefMain', drop=False, inplace=True)

lst = [df['Name'].values]
new_df = df.copy()

# Iterate until all values in 'Name' are NaN 
while new_df['Name'].notna().any():
    new_df = df.reindex(new_df['RefSecondary'])
    lst.append(new_df['Name'].values)
```

You get the following list of arrays `lst`:

```
[array(['test', 'bet', 'get', 'set', 'net'], dtype=object),
 array(['get', 'test', 'set', nan, 'test'], dtype=object),
 array(['set', 'get', nan, nan, 'get'], dtype=object),
 array([nan, 'set', nan, nan, 'set'], dtype=object),
 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)]
```

Now you can join strings and create a new df.

```
result = ['/'.join(filter(np.nan.__eq__, i)) for i in zip(*lst[::-1])]
result = pd.DataFrame({'Result': result, 'RefMain': df['RefMain'].values})
```

Final result:

```
             Result  RefMain
0      set/get/test        3
1  set/get/test/bet        4
2           set/get        2
3               set        1
4  set/get/test/net        5
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does the work with `merges`. It is a bit twisted, but it should run fast because (maybe because) there are no row iterations.

In short, it keeps merging until all new `RefSecondary` values are null.

I guess it could be further optimized masking the `merge` operation as well.

```
df_ref = df.copy()

df.rename(columns={'Name':'Result'},inplace=True)

while not np.all(pd.isnull(df['RefSecondary'])):
    df = df.merge(df_ref,how='left',
                  left_on='RefSecondary',right_on='RefMain',
                  suffixes=['_old',''])
    mask_=pd.notnull(df['RefMain'])
    df.loc[mask_,'Result'] = df.loc[mask_,'Result']+'/'+df.loc[mask_,'Name']
    df.drop(['RefSecondary_old','RefMain_old','Name'],axis='columns',inplace=True)


df = df[['Result']].join(df_ref['RefMain'])
```

Source data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['test',2,3],
                    ['bet',3,4],
                    ['get',1,2],
                    ['set','null',1],
                    ['net',3,5]], 
              columns=['Name','RefSecondary','RefMain'])
```

By the way, this code makes assumes that the original data is consistent. For instance, if there were a cycle in the links, it would be trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: `df.loc[mask_,'Result'] = df.loc[mask_,'Result']+'/'+df.loc[mask_,'index']` this line shows `KeyError: 'Result'`

Comment: There is no column `index` which is being renamed in the code above. Also `Result` is a column I have created in the output dataframe.

Comment: I adapted my response to your comments.